# Passing multivalue parameter to a subreport

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, subreport, multivalue

I'm having a problem when working with `multivalue` parameters between reports.

I have a main report in which I have defined a multivalue paramer, which I use to run a SQL query to populate its dataset. The parameter is used in the WHERE clause in the following way:

```
WHERE values IN (@parameter)
```

It's working fine and it retreives the expected data.

Then this main report passes this parameter to a subreport. The parameter is also defined as multivalue in the subreport and, as far as I can see in the parameter's dropdownlist it receives the values in the right way. Something like this: A, B, C

The thing is that the query that populates the subreport's dataset returns nothing.
It also has a WHERE clause defined as in the main report (which is already working)

```
WHERE values IN (@parameter)
```

If I run the query manually, hardcoding the values to something like this:

```
WHERE values IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

it works, but when I try to use the parameter it doesn't. So, somehow it's losing the format or the values in the way.

I tried this solution in the subreport's dataset definition, which was proposed in another thread:

```
 =join(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,",")
```

But it doesn't work for me, the dataset is still empty.

Any ideas about what I'm missing?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just created the report from scratch again and it worked. I must have forgotten something in the middle.

Anyway, just in case somebody needs it, the two parameters, the one in the main report and the one in the subreport , must be defined as multivalue. 
Then in your query you should use `IN` in your `WHERE` clase, something like this:

```
WHERE field IN (@parameter)
```

And nothing else is needed. I didn't need to do the following:

```
=join(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,",")
```

It just worked for me

Answer (score 15):

This should "just work." Make sure that the Parameter in the subreport is set up as multivalue, and I usually use the exact same query as in the parent report to provide "Available Values."

Check that you are passing the entire parameter to the subreport: In subreport properties on the parent report, the parameter's value should read `[@MyParamName]` not `<<Expr>>`. If it reads as the latter, edit the expression and make sure it doesn't have a (0) at the end. but `=Parameters!MyParamName.Value` is correct, **not** `=Parameters!MyParamName.Value(0)`

Comment: You are right, this should "just work", but it didn't. So, I deleted the report and created it from zero again, it worked. Apparently I must have forgotten something in the middle. Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get mine working.  Important: **"Parameter in the subreport is set up as multivalue, and use the exact same query as in the parent report to provide Available Values."**.  Important: **"In subreport properties on the parent report, the parameter's value should read `[@MyParamName]` not `<<Expr>>`"**.  These tips did it for me.

Comment: I did what you proposed(check if everything is implemented as in the main report) and found the problem. I use Report Builder for creating reports and in my data source, instead of coding, I went to the Filters tab from DataSet Properties and added there my field, the operation I want to be used (IN), and the list of values which is the multiple value parameter. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you did, as I was drawn here by having the same problem.
The subreports were setup fine, but when entering the parameter binding in the parent report, the `Value` drop down did not offer my parameter, so I used expression builder to select it. This left the grey `<< Expr >>` marker in the value and would only work when I had only one value selected from the list. When I replaced this with `[@MyParam]` it worked fine regardless of the number of values selected. When I had a look at the value expression builder had created a bit closer it had `=Parameters!MyParam.Value(0)`. Removing the `(0)` also fixes it.